# How do you define broke and broke into?

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrasal-verbs

How do you define *broke* and *broke into* here?

OP: "If you're not making six figures by the time you're 40, you fail at life."

P1: "whew... I just made it... **broke into** 6 figures at 39."

P2: "I **broke** 6 figures at 29. Never got much past that though."

Comment: *Broke* past the figurative "barrier" at $99,999 into the six-figure range at $100,000.

Comment: That's right. This is a [metaphor](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf), not a fact about the verb _break_, or even the phrasal verb _break into_. It's just `TIME is MOTION` with a moving subject and a frangible barrier.

Comment: Protip: don't use the tag [tag:words].

Comment: I'm really itching to close this one as General Reference, but I'll restrain myself. *Please* lets not have anyone ask *"What does [break the sound barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_barrier#Breaking_the_sound_barrier_as_a_human_projectile) mean?"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Broke* means to undo, smash, tear etc. Here it's metaphorically picturing the ¤100,000 limit as being broken like an athlete breaking a tape. It's such a common metaphor as to have moved past cliché into a new meaning.

*Broke into* means to break something so as to gain access to something or somewhere (burglars break into houses, and in some jurisdictions this is a separate offence to both the vandalism and the trespassing entailed). Here the speaker is referring to the fact that they stayed within the ¤100,000+ region after this - they moved from one state to another, and stayed in the latter. It's a bit of a clumsy use though, to my mind.

Priorities about what counts as "failing at life", is another matter...

Comment: Just my impression, but I think using the phrase "broke into (x region)" comes not so much from breaking into a physical location as it does the aviation term, "breaking into" as in "We broke into clear air above 4,000 ft..."  Like a plane "breaks into" a new stratum, so the speaker "broke into" the six figure stratum...

Answer (score 0):

A good start might be to read

> Fillmore's "[The Grammar of *Hitting* and *Breaking*](http://www.icsi.berkeley.edu/pubs/ai/ICSI_grammarofhitting12.pdf)".

There's quite a lot going on here.